# Como funciona a classe ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource do spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Ola, estou apredendo a mexer com o spring, estou montando uma api e estou usando o seguinte tutorial para aprender a trabalhar com mensagens de erro personalizadas:
[tutorial ensinando a gerar mensagens de erro personalizadas](https://dev.to/ledsonsilva/tratamento-de-erros-personalizados-para-apis-rest-com-spring-boot-4dpd)

durante o tutorial eu vi a classe **ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource** tentei olhar na documentação do spring para entender-la, mas não consegui compreender bem a descrição.
**Por fim, minha dúvida é a seguinte:**

Qual a finalidade da classe ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, como ela funciona e onde ela se encaixa dentro desse contexto onde preciso gerar mesagens de erro personalizadas, como mostrado no link acima?

*Sou iniciante, por isso a dificuldade em entender a documentação, se puderem me ajudar, agradeço muito!*

Answer (score 0):

ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource é uma implementação da interface MessageSource. O MessageSource basicamente serve para você alterar a mensagem de erro quando faz uma validação (ex: a mensagem que vai aparecer se um @NotEmpty falhar) e essa implementação faz a busca da mensagem num arquivo de Properties (com modelo "property=value").
Docs:
[MessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) 
[ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html)